# Is insecure to cast a void * pointer?

Tags: c

For example in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char i = 0;
  char j = 0;
  char *p = &i;
  void *q = p;
  int *pp = q;
  printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
  *pp = -1;
  printf("%d %d\n", i, j);

  return 0;
}
```

if I compile with gcc version 8.1.0 x64 (Ubuntu 8.1.0-5ubuntu1~16.04) the output is:
0 0
-1 -1
now, I use a cast to int *

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char i = 0;
  char j = 0;
  char *p = &i;
  void *q = p;
  int *pp = (int *)q;
  printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
  *pp = -1;
  printf("%d %d\n", i, j);

  return 0;
}
```

the result is the same as the previous.
With clang-6.0 x64 the output is:
0 0
-1 0
Is the code apparently a buffer overflow?
I hope I've explained that clearly.

Comment: There is no difference between the 2 codes, and yes, you are writing outside of `i`. The result of this print then depends on how `i` and `j` are stored in memory. Either way though, it's a bad idea.

Comment: The `void *` is not related to your problem as it did not change the result. Also adding the cast did not change anything. How is your question related to the casting of a `void*`? What does clang product for your first code?

Comment: I would assume tht gcc and clang produce different layout of your variabltes on the stack and depending on that your (illegal) assignment to `*pp` hits `j` or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have *two* problems:

The first is that you break [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The second problem is that on most modern platforms the size of an `int` is *four* bytes, and the pointer `pp` is pointing only to a *single* byte. The assignment you make to `*pp` will therefore write out of bounds and *also* lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Cast or no cast, you are essentially try to use incompatible types, leading to violating strict aliasing rules.

According to `C11`, chapter §6.5,

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:88)
>
> — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>   object,
>
> — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the
>   effective type of the object,
>
> — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>
> — a character type.

But, you try to access the memory allocated for a `char` via an `int` type. This violates strict aliasing.

That said, the standard guarantees that size of a `char` is 1 byte, size of an `int` is `>=` `char`. So, the access would be out of bound and lead to undefined behavior.